# Can Kentico 11 API be utilized in the same way Kentico Cloud is used?

Tags: kentico

We are currently utilizing Kentico 11 for our website. We just reupped our support for Kentico 11 so we don't have any current plans to make any moves.

However, I'm really impressed by the headless CMS approach that Kentico Cloud encourages. My question is, can Kentico 11 api be utilized in a way where I can use Kentico 11 as a purely Content Management System and build an Angular application that will utilize Kentico's built in API.

Or is the only way to do a headless CMS project (using Angular and Kentico) is to purchase a Kentico Cloud account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Kentico's Roadmap](https://www.kentico.com/product/roadmap), you'll see they are moving towards an MVC first approach vs. Portal Engine first approach.  That being said, you CAN simply use Kentico CMS/EMS as your content management system and simply have a second web app utilizing MVC to make calls to Kentico to get the data out and displayed properly.

You can [check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc) for more on how to get started with this in v11.

There are some articles out there from some well known Kentico Developers/Agencies (you can search for "Kentico MVC" on troubles they have overcome with MVC and Kentico as well as approaches.  Short story is you can do what you're asking without Kentico Cloud but Kentico Cloud would be a great addition if you needed multi-channel content delivery.

There is a [great post here](https://kenticocloud.com/blog/5-questions-about-kentico-ems-kentico-cloud) about the differences and some common questions between Kentico Cloud and Kentico EMS.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. One additional point of clarification, when you say I could build a second web app utilizing MVC, do you mean as in an asp .net MVC application?

Comment: Correct. Folks who use Kentico and MVC will have the Kentico admin website your content editors log into as one site and then the front facing website you'd create as an MVC application as another site both connected to the same database.